# Listview is not scrolling when focusing on entry control within ViewCell in xamarin.forms iOS

Tags: ios, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have entry controls within listview. When I focus entry in ViewCell  soft keyboard appears and it hides the entry control because listview was not scrolled to bring the text entry to view area.

To overcome this, I tried to use listview within ScrollView but it doesn't solve the issue.

Can you please suggest any solution to resolve this issue as we used entry control within listview in many pages in our project.

Thanks in advance.

**Version details:**

Xamarin 4.0.0.1689
Xamarin.Forms 1.5.0
Xamarin.iOS 9.2.1.5.1

**Sample Source Code:**

```
<ViewCell>
    <Grid ColumnSpacing="15" Padding="20,20,30,20" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Text="{Binding Description}" XAlign="Start" YAlign="Center" Style="{DynamicResource SectionBlueColorLbl}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
        <CustomControl:CustomEntry Keyboard="Numeric" Text="{Binding WeightText}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsOccupied}" Focused="WeightEntry_focused" Unfocused="Weight_Unfocused"  HeightRequest="39" WidthRequest="100"  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="Transparent" TextColor="#FFFFFF">
            <CustomControl:CustomEntry.Behaviors>
                <FormsLib:IntegerValidationBehavior MaxLength="5" />
            </CustomControl:CustomEntry.Behaviors>
        </CustomControl:CustomEntry>

        <Label Text="{Binding Location.Arm}" XAlign="End" YAlign="Center" Style="{DynamicResource CaptionLabelSmall}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" />

        <Label IsVisible="false" BindingContext="Location" Text="{Binding LatArm}" XAlign="End" YAlign="Center" Style="{DynamicResource CaptionLabelSmall}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" />

        <Label Text="{Binding MomentText}" XAlign="End" YAlign="Center" Style="{DynamicResource CaptionLabelSmall}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" />

        <Label IsVisible="false"  Text="{Binding LatMomentText}" XAlign="End" YAlign="Center" Style="{DynamicResource CaptionLabelSmall}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" />
    </Grid>
</ViewCell>
```

Comment: Can you share your code for the page the view cell is being used in?

Comment: Tested on Android and iPod with XF 2 and this appears to work. Is upgrading a possibility?

Comment: @JodyAndrews Thanks for your response. Have upgraded to XF 2. It works for me. but it is not working in a listview which contains context action(Swipe). Can you please suggest any solution if you have faced the same? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That looks like a bug. As a workaround separate the ViewCell into it's own file, in the codebehind add an EventHandler for the Entry Focussed event and use the ScrollTo method on the parent listview to ScrollToPosition.Center... (example uses a static property for demonstration, don't do this, just use messaging or something)..
entry.Focused += (object sender, FocusEventArgs e) => {
    Entry myEntry = (Entry)sender;
    ListViewFoo.MyListView.ScrollTo(myEntry.Parent.BindingContext, ScrollToPosition.Center, true);

If this isn't too clear then just update the question and i'll add an answer.

Comment: @JodyAndrews, sorry for delayed response. I have tried as your suggestion. but listview is not scrolling.